# How can I expand li elements to container size?

Tags: html, css, size, html-lists

I have the following HTML:

```css
#main-menu {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 600px;
}

.menu {
  list-style: none outside none;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu-item {
  float: left;    
}

.menu-item a {
  border: 1px solid red;  
}
```

```html
<div id="main-menu">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item #1</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item #2</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item #3</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item #4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How do I make the li elements automatically expand euqally to the fixed width of the container?

Thanks in advance! :-)

CodePen link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JoKgXz

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByzXpp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated you codepen codes..

**CSS**

```
#main-menu {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul, li{
  margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.menu {
  list-style: none outside none;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu-item {
  float: left; 
  width:25%;
}

.menu-item a {
  border: 1px solid red;  
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPrQbg)

Answer (score 0):

First remove all margin and padding from the `.menu`. As you have four items in the menu, add `width: 25%` to the `.menu-item`. I've added a `display: block` to the `<a>` tag to make it fill the entire width of the `.menu-item`. As you use `float: left` the menu-items won't make the `.menu` container grow. The `.menu:after` adds a clearfix to have the menu contain all menu items.

Instead of `float: left` you could also have opted for a `display: inline-block`. In this case the clearfix wouldn't be necessary, but you need to make sure that the menu items don't have any whitespace (e.g. a newline) between them. Put them on one line like `...</li><li>...` otherwise there will be some space between the menu items.

If you need some padding on the menu item make sure to add `box-sizing: border-box` as otherwise the width will refer to the content only. This means that after adding the padding the menu item will take up more than 25% of the width, which makes the last menu item wrap to a new line.

```css
#main-menu {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 600px;
}

.menu {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear:both;
}

.menu-item {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

.menu-item a {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;  
}
```

```html
<div id="main-menu">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item #1</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item #2</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item #3</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item #4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have a proper CSS reset and use the `box-sizing:border-box` property.

This option has the virtue of not requiring set widths on the `li`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#main-menu {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 600px;
}
.menu {
  list-style: none outside none;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.menu-item {
  display: table-cell;
}
.menu-item a {
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-menu">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item #1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item #2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item #3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item #4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </d
```